# Filter django QuerySet on subclassed type (multi-table inheritance)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm looking for an efficient model manager method that uses the following class structure to generate a QuerySet, as described below:

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class SuperModel(models.Model):
    date_of_interest = models.DateField(...)
    # <other model_fields>

class SubA(SuperModel):
    # <other model_fields>

class SubB(SuperModel):
    # <other model_fields>

class SubC(SuperModel):
    # <other model_fields>

#somewhere else (eg. views.py)
...    
query_set = SuperModel.objects.filter(date_of_interest=today)
qs_to_list = [e for e in query_set if hasattr(e, 'subb') or hasattr(e, 'subc')]
```

**I would like to keep `qs_to_list` a QuerySet, so I'm searching for a way to filter with a model manager method, based on the type of subclass.**  As noted, I'm using multitable inheritance with `abstract=False`  and implicitly using the `OneToOneField` created with this type of inheritance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

SuperModel.objects.filter(
    Q(subb__isnull=False) | Q(subc__isnull=False),
    date_of_interest=today
).distinct()
```

This will thus make `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s on the `SubB` and `SubC` model, and if there is a record with this JOINing for which the `SubB` and/or `SubC` is not `NULL`, we know that it is of type `SubB` or `SubC`.

Comment: Worked great for my purpose.  Thanks.